# Filezilla locks itself and cannot move through folders for a few seconds

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am getting a strange error in Filezilla and it has been ocurring for the last months.

When I connect to a server I can move files, delete files, etc perfectly. However if I leave it on the background and return to it Filezilla blocks itself and I cannot move through folders. When you click in the folder nothing happens and after a few tries the connection breaks and Filezilla reconnects again and starts working, but eventually connection will freeze again.

It is happening regardless of the server I connect and it is happening in diferent Filezilla installations.

This is an example of the logs:

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/httpdocs/application/modules/default/views/scripts/payment"...
Command:    CWD /httpdocs/application/modules/default/views/scripts/payment
Error:  Disconnected from server: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
Status: Connecting to 217.xxx.xxx.xxx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/httpdocs/application/modules/default/views/scripts/payment"...
Status: Directory listing of "/httpdocs/application/modules/default/views/scripts/payment" successful
```

The problem occurs in the first line, you click to a folder an nothing happens aftel a while the command CWD appears and the rest happens instantly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This happens with any connection or just a single one?

Comment: Happens on all the connections, connected to 4 different servers, and connected from different computers(work and home)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some firewall or router on the way between your machine and the server(s) is killing idle connections, without properly notifying the connected parties.

So the FTP client notices that the connection is dead, only when it tries to use the connection and times out waiting for any response.

Try setting connection keep-alives in FileZilla preferences.
In FileZilla main window go to *Edit > Settings > Connection > FTP* and check *Send FTP keep-alive commands*.

Comment: It worked for some time, but I get the locks again after a while

Comment: Could you try the same with [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/)? It not only issues "keepalive" commands, but keeps listing remote directory now and then, what could work better to prevent the disconnects. See [how to enable keepalives](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_connection).